# How to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{(\ln(x+1))^x}{(2x)^{x/3}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use.
Can you show a method for the resolution with asymptotic approximations, or with variable change(so without Hopital)? Thanks

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{(\ln(x+1))^x}{(2x)^{x/3}}\right)$$

Comment: $x \to \infty?$

Comment: Probably there is a typo. There should be $x\to +\infty$

Comment: yeah i changed.

Comment: Please : **L'Hôpital** or **L'Hospital**

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici With a lowercase “l”, please. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg. No, sir since it is a family name : **Guillaume François Antoine, marquis de L'Hôpital**

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The French Wikipedia page has both; they should decide which one is correct.

Comment: @egreg. You are totally right concerning the French Wikipedia page but, to me, Frenchman, it is wrong and, moreover, having both in the same page is fully unconsistent. Cheers :-)

Comment: Whether it be l'Hôpital or L'Hôpital, the limit is without him :)

Comment: @ClementC. Very good point, indeed !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually **Hôpital** is the *nouveau françois* for **Hospital**, this is the meaning of the '^' (suppress the following *s* and add '^' to the vowel)

Comment: @ringø. You are totally correct and we still have that in usual French : for example **Hostellerie Xyz** looks smarter than  **Hôtellerie Xyz**. The first one will charge you more for the same junk !

Comment: I guess it must be $0$ because $x^{2/3}$ is of higher order than $\ln x$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my solution I compare two graphs.

At first: 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln(x + 1)}{\sqrt[3]{2x}}\right)^x,$$

as you know $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(q)^x = 0$$ if $$ -1 < q < 1$$

and then I checked is it true that: $$\ln(x + 1)<\sqrt[3]{2x}.$$

I draw 2 graphs for $x>0$

[image]

As you can see for $x>0$ inequality is always real so limit is $0$.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is an excellent idea. However, a graph can be misleading. To make the argument more rigorous, one should first show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(x+1)/(2x)^{1/3} = 0$. Hence for sufficiently large $x$,  we know that $0 < \ln(x+1)/(2x)^{1/3} \le q = 1/2$. Therefore also $\left(\ln(x+1)/(2x)^{1/3} \right)^x \le \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x$ which converges to 0.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your supplement!

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor expansions:
$$
\ln(x+1) = \ln x + \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = \ln x + \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
and therefore
$$
\ln(x+1)^x = e^{x\ln\left(\ln x + \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) }
= e^{x\ln\ln x + x\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x\ln x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x\ln x}\right)\right) }
= e^{x\ln\ln x + \frac{1}{\ln x} + o\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}\right) } = e^{x\ln\ln x + o(1)}.
$$
The denominator, however, becomes 
$$
(2x)^{x/3} = e^{\frac{x}{3}\ln(2x)} = e^{\frac{1}{3}x\ln x + \frac{\ln 2}{3}x}
$$
so that overall, the quantity considered is, at infinity,
$$
e^{x\ln\ln x - \frac{1}{3}x\ln x - \frac{\ln 2}{3}x + o(1)}.
$$
But the limit of $x\ln\ln x - \frac{1}{3}x\ln x - \frac{\ln 2}{3}x + o(1)$ is $-\infty$ (can you see why? The term that dominates is $\frac{1}{3}x\ln x$), so by continuity of $\exp$ the limit is $0$.

Comment: Taylor expansion is not the right approach to deal with limits at $\infty$.

Comment: In this case, by factoring we make appear 1/x, so we get a limit at 0 to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

we will use the fact that $\ln(x + a) = \ln x + \frac a x + \cdots$ for $x$ large.  $$ \text{ let }y = \frac{(\ln(x+1))^x}{(2x)^{x/3}} .$$ then 
$$\begin{align}\ln y &= x \ln(\ln(x+1))-\frac x3\left(\ln 2 + \ln x\right)\\
&=x\ln\left(\ln x +  \frac 1 x + \cdots\right)-\frac x3\left(\ln 2 + \ln x\right)\\
&=x\left(\ln(\ln x)+\frac 1{x\ln x}  +\cdots\right) - \frac x3\left(\ln 2 + \ln x\right)\\
&=-\frac x3\ln x+\cdots \to -\infty \end{align} $$ therefore 
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{(\ln(x+1))^x}{(2x)^{x/3}}\right)=0. $$